# Missing field with serde fails to set to default value

Tags: csv, rust, serde

I have a very simple struct here to deserialize from a string

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
use csv;
#[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
struct Test {
    x: f64,
    #[serde(default)]
    up: f64,
}

#[test]
fn deserialise() {
    let s = "x,up\n0.0,";

    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_reader(s.as_bytes());
    for row in rdr.deserialize() {
        let option: Test = row.expect("Failure");
        dbg!(&option);
    }
}
}
```

I would expect the field 'up' to default to 0.0 as it's missing from the file. Using `up: Option<f64>` works but it's not a true representation of the data model.

What am I doing wrong here?

It fails with

```
thread 'tests::deserialise' panicked at 'Failure: Error(Deserialize { pos: Some(Position { byte: 111, line: 2, record: 1 }), err: DeserializeError { field: Some(12), kind: ParseFloat(ParseFloatError { kind: Empty }) } })', data_model\examples\upload_options.rs:80:41
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "data_model"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "^1.0", features = ["derive"] }
csv = "^1"
```

Comment: How do you encode the empty string in a CSV? It doesn't contain any commas or other illegal characters so it doesn't need to be in quotes. It is probably attempting to deserialize an empty string as `f32` because CSV is fairly ambiguous as a data format. If you removed the comma before the empty value it may start working again, however I have no idea how you would make the first value in the row empty.

Comment: Changing to `let s = "x,up\n0.0";` interestingly gives this error `Error(UnequalLengths { pos: Some(Position { byte: 5, line: 2, record: 1 }), expected_len: 2, len: 1 })`

In the real file, this blank field is in the middle of 10 other fields; so I was trying to reduce it to the minimum viable example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credits to https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv/issues/109#issuecomment-372709974.

This is a limitation to the CSV format because it doesn't distinguish between an empty string and a non-existent cell. So you need to work around this by telling serde to deserialize empty cells into the default value.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct Test {
    pub x: f64,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "default_if_empty")]
    pub up: f64,
}

fn default_if_empty<'de, D, T>(de: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
where
    D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    T: serde::Deserialize<'de> + Default,
{
    use serde::Deserialize;
    Option::<T>::deserialize(de).map(|x| x.unwrap_or_else(|| T::default()))
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn deserialise() {
        let s = "x,up\n0.0,";

        let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_reader(s.as_bytes());
        for row in rdr.deserialize() {
            let option: Test = row.expect("Failure");
            dbg!(&option);
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ cargo test -- --nocapture
running 1 test
[src/lib.rs:28] &option = Test {
    x: 0.0,
    up: 0.0,
}
test tests::deserialise ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```